# minimal polynomial of roots of irreducible polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-groups, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, the highest degree coefficient of $f$ is $1$. Let $\omega\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(\omega)=0$. Can we obtain that the minimal polynomial of $\omega$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $f$? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g$ be the minimal polynomial of $\omega$. Then $f\in(g)$, i.e. $g\mid f$. By irreducibility of $f$, $g$ and $f$ can differ by at most a unit factor.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\, $ If a principal ideal $\ne 1$ contains an irreducible element then that element generates the ideal (else the generator would be a *proper* divisor of the irreducible).